# Using Selenium RC with C# and Nunit; how to Generate test case result report?

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, rc

I'm using Selenium RC with C# and Nunit, problem is Result Report.
I'm not able to report test cases result, 
In Nunit I can execute only single DLL what if i have 4 DLL, how can I club 4 DLL  result in Single report?

Do some one have idea abt the process please explain.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're running your unit tests using NUnit console on the command line then you can specify to run the tests from within multiple assemblies and to output to a single file.

e.g. nunit-console /xml:results.xml assembly1.dll assembly2.dll assembly3.dll

Detailed in the NUnit documentation [here](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.5.9)